# margin of an element at specific breakpoints doesn't work in Tailwind

Tags: css, plugins, themes, next.js, tailwind-css

I was trying to set margin of an `div` element at specific breakpoints by adding a `{screen}: prefix` but it won't work.
What I tried is below;

```
<div className={'flex justify-center'}>
  <div className={'w-full my-8 sm:my-20 md:my-48'}>
    <div {...props}>
      {children}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Inspecting mode, I could identify that only `my-8` class works.

[image]

All classes of Tailwind work well and `flex` for responsive works as well, but the margin(padding) for responsive doesn't work.
I use Next.js and Tailwind CSS.

Comment: So you did try other stuff like `sm:bg-red-500` and it worked but margin and padding don't? Maybe your PurgeCss setup isn't correct?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I found the answer on my own.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry, but I figured it out by myself.
It's because of tailwind config.

Since it's not the project from scratch, I had no chance to check the config.

So I figured it out by modifying margin variant to:

```
  // tailwind.config.js
  module.exports = {
    variants: {
      // ...
-     margin: ['hover'],
+     margin: ['responsive', 'hover'],
    }
  }
```

reference:
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/margin#responsive-and-pseudo-class-variants

**UPDATE 11/2021**

In Nov, 2021, Tailwind released version 3.0 and it has some breaking changes.

One of the changes, you can remove `variants` section from your `tailwind.config.js` file.

Reference: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/upgrade-guide#remove-variant-configuration